# How to retrieve value from jQuery spinner to put into an asp.net label?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I been racking out on my brain trying to figure this out. I have asked this question a couple times but I'm still at a loss.

Its back to my jquery spinner issue.

I have this function...

```
function updateTopBottom() {
        var $el = $('#topbottom'),
            m;


        m = $el.find('input').map(function () {
            return $(this).spinner('value');
        }).get().join(' ');


        $el.find('.c-output').html(m);
    }
```

I understand what its doing but I just can't get it to put the value to a label, so I can access it from my code behind.
I have added a label to my page and changed this part

```
$el.find('.c-output').html(m);
```

to look for the label that I dropped on my page, its ID is Label1 and I have removed the .c-output and added the #Label1 but it doesn't put the spinner value to the label, it just disappears.

the .c-output is a div tag that looks likes this...

```
<div class="c-output"></div>
```

I have no idea how to even access the value from there to put into a label.
The end result is I need to grab the value from the spinner and put that value into a label so I can access it.

I been trying this for the last couple hours and I seem to be going nowhere real quick.

Comment: are you sure that the `c-output` is a descendant of `$el`? try `$('.c-output').html(m);`

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm76/ACLpX/ it works like its supposed to, I just want to be able to put a value to a label and not the div tag, or at least get the value that's in the div tag to show up in a label

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nCsd9/1/ ?

Comment: Yes like that but using an asp label, instead of the div

Comment: not an ASP guy... so not sure what you mean by ASP label

Comment: Well, seeing as ASP labels get rendered as normal labels and this is all happening client-side, why don't you just use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nCsd9/2/)

Comment: oh ok sorry, this is an asp label... <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="label"></asp:Label>, I know I can access labels and stuff from the markup by using <%= %> just don't know how to access code in the markup

Comment: @AdamBotley because I don't know how to access the value from my code behind page

Comment: Well then this is an ASP.NET question

Comment: I had a question like this tagged with asp.net and it got edited

Comment: Did you explain that you wanted to access the ASP control's value from code behind and how you wanted to do that? (eg postBack)

Comment: I can access asp controls, that's not the issue. I am new to jquery and its been an uphill battle trying to access the spinners value. The issue is not knowing how to access that value from the markup. That's why I figure if I put into an asp label then I can access the value easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest using `HiddenField` rather than `Label` for you scenario:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSpinnerValue" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

Now you can modify your JavaScript like this:

```
function updateTopBottom() {
    var $el = $('#topbottom'), m;

    m = $el.find('input[type!="hidden"]').map(function () {
        return $(this).spinner('value');
    }).get().join(' ');

    $('input[name$="hfSpinnerValue"]').val(m);
}
```

And you will be to access the value of `m` in your server side code through `hfSpinnerValue.Value`.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer and am going to try this out in the morning, its 5 am where I am and I been racking my brain out trying to figure this out and I believe that you did. Thank you sir.